# Displaylink installation Kernel version 3.13.0-55-generic is too old

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, displaylink

I am following this guide: [How to install displaylink on ubuntu](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu)

To install displaylink on my ubuntu 14.04.

Everything works fine however when i go for the last step and attempt to install the `.run` file i get the following error message:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies. Missing component: Kernel version 3.13.0-55-generic is too old. At least 3.14 is required.
```

This is a fatal error, cannot install DisplayLink Linux Software.

I have attempted to upgrade my `Kernel` version using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
```

However when i attempt this i get that everything is up to date

```
marc@marc:~/Videos$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I am unsure what to do here :(

**My /boot directory**

```
abi-3.13.0-45-generic         initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic
abi-3.13.0-46-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.13.0-55-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.13.0-63-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.16.0-48-generic         System.map-3.13.0-45-generic
config-3.13.0-45-generic      System.map-3.13.0-46-generic
config-3.13.0-46-generic      System.map-3.13.0-55-generic
config-3.13.0-55-generic      System.map-3.13.0-63-generic
config-3.13.0-63-generic      System.map-3.16.0-48-generic
config-3.16.0-48-generic      vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic.efi.signed
```

Comment: @Arronical Sadly it did not :(

Comment: @Arronical Ive added my boot directory to the question

Comment: @Arronical il try and reboot

Comment: @Arronical After reboot it installed correctly ..God why didnt i try that before :s

Comment: Good news! I'm going to make this into an answer and delete my comments to clean this post up a bit, would you mind accepting once I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done the correct thing by installing the Utopic HWE stack kernel, but will need to reboot to start using the 3.16 kernel. Your install of Displaylink should proceed as planned after that.

If you want to get some space back in your `/boot` directory then do:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will get rid of any unnecessary kernel files and other unused dependencies.